# Gnuplot concentric circle plots

Tags: plot, gnu, geometry, pie-chart

I would like to do a concentric circle plot consisting of three circles of different colour, and different size according to the quantity of money they represent.

```
32015 TOTAL AMOUNT OF INVESTMENT  
 $M $   % CONTRIBUTION   
 1678   0.0524    INNER CIRCLE 
10330   0.3226    FIRST SHELL
20007   0.6249    OUTER SHELL
```

Does anyone know how I would do this ? I tried to just plot three circles starting from (0,0) and to select different colours. However all I get is one big circle of the sum of the square root of the radii selected.

```
plot ’data’ using 1:2:(sqrt($3)) with circles
```

data as in:

```
0        1.678  0       violet
0       10.330  0       silver
0       20.007  0       gold
```

Thank you very much for your help

This is what it should look like but with the relative areas of the three regions adjusted:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot draws the circles in the order of your lines in the data file, so the smaller circles are being overdrawn by the final, large circle. You need to sort the data first. One way is, if you are on Linux or another system that has the "sort" routine,

`set style fill transparent solid noborder
plot '< sort -k2nr data' u (0):(0):(sqrt($2)):(column(0)) with circles lc var`

This will cycle through some colors. I wasn't sure if you want to take the colors from the words in your file.